# How to pass dynamic arguments to usePrepareContractWrite in Wagmi?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js, react, wagmi

I have to pass token amount as argument on a function call. The amount is dynamic and coming from a text box when a user click button (for partial amount submission). There is another button that allow to submit all available token amount.

So if total token amount is 5000. A user can input any amount in between 1 to 5000 in text box and click the button which invoke `write` function from `useContractWrite` hook. And then there is another button that when clicked by the user should pass 5000 as argument and invoke `write` function.

Below are the 2 approaches I tired, but both is not working. I have commented the respective part of my code to make my point more clear.

**1st approach (Using state hook)**

```js
import { BigNumber, utils } from "ethers";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  usePrepareContractWrite,
  useContractWrite,
  useWaitForTransaction,
} from "wagmi";
import { useDebounce } from "@/hooks/usehooks";
import {
  tokenAddress,
  tokenAbi,
} from "../../constants/Token";

const submitToken: React.FC = ({tokenAmount}) => {
  const [partialAmount, setPartialAmount] = useState<string>("0");
  const [totalTokenAmount, setTotalTokenAmount] = useState<number>(tokenAmount);
  const [amountToPut, setAmountToPut] = useState<BigNumber>(
    BigNumber.from("0")
  ); // this state is argument 
  const debountAmount = useDebounce(partialAmount, 500); //rate limiting

  const {
    config,
    error: prepareError,
    isError: isPrepareError,
  } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: tokenAddress,
    abi: tokenAbi,
    functionName: "myWritableFun",
    args: [amountToPut], // This doesn't update when we change the `partialAmount` in function below
  });

  const {
    data,
    error: contractError,
    isError: isContractError,
    write,
  } = useContractWrite(config);

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: data?.hash,
  });

  const putPartialToken = () => {
    if (isNaN(Number(debountAmount))) {
      alert("Not a valid amount");
      return;
    }
    // we are checking this in contract too
    if (Number(debountAmount) > totalTokenAmount) {
      alert("Amount overflow!");
      return;
    }
    //the below doesn't work on first click So,basically this is where I am not sure how to set `amountToPut`
    setAmountToPut(utils.parseEther(debountAmount));    
    write?.();  
  };

  const putAllToken = async () => {    
    setAmountToPut(utils.parseEther(totalTokenAmount.toString())); 
    write?.();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
      <p>
        Submit All token{" "}
         {/* Submit all amount, first event */}
        <button onClick={putAllToken} disabled={!write || isLoading}>
          Submit All Amount
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>
        Sumbit partial amount
        <input
          type="text"
          id="partialSubmit"
          onChange={(e) => setPartialAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
       {/* Submit partial amount, second event */}
        <button onClick={putPartialToken} disabled={!write || isLoading}>
          Submit Partial Amount
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default submitToken;
```

**The 2nd approach (using a variable)**

```js
import { BigNumber, utils } from "ethers";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  usePrepareContractWrite,
  useContractWrite,
  useWaitForTransaction,
} from "wagmi";
import { useDebounce } from "@/hooks/usehooks";
import {
  tokenAddress,
  tokenAbi,
} from "../../constants/Token";

const submitToken: React.FC = ({tokenAmount}) => {
  const [partialAmount, setPartialAmount] = useState<string>("0");
  const [totalTokenAmount, setTotalTokenAmount] = useState<number>(tokenAmount);
  
  const debountAmount = useDebounce(partialAmount, 500); //rate limiting

  // I am using variable instead of state
  let amountToPut = utils.parseEther("0");

  const {
    config,
    error: prepareError,
    isError: isPrepareError,
  } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: tokenAddress,
    abi: tokenAbi,
    functionName: "myWritableFun",
    args: [amountToPut], // This doesn't update when we change the `partialAmount` in function below
  });

  const {
    data,
    error: contractError,
    isError: isContractError,
    write,
  } = useContractWrite(config);

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: data?.hash,
  });

  const putPartialToken = () => {
    if (isNaN(Number(debountAmount))) {
      alert("Not a valid amount");
      return;
    }
    // we are checking this in contract too
    if (Number(debountAmount) > totalTokenAmount) {
      alert("Amount overflow!");
      return;
    }

    //This does change the value of `amountToPut` but it is not updated in `usePrepareContractWrite` function above 
    amountToPut = utils.parseEther(debouncedStakeAmount); 
    write?.();  
  };

  const putAllToken = async () => {    
    //This does change the value of `amountToPut` but it is not updated in `usePrepareContractWrite` function above 
    amountToPut = utils.parseEther(totalTokenAmount.toString()); 
    write?.();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
      <p>
        Submit All token{" "}
        {/* Submit all amount, first event */}
        <button onClick={putAllToken} disabled={!write || isLoading}>
          Submit All Amount
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>
        Sumbit partial amount
        <input
          type="text"
          id="partialSubmit"
          onChange={(e) => setPartialAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
        {/* Submit partial amount, second event */}
        <button onClick={putPartialToken} disabled={!write || isLoading}>
          Submit Partial Amount
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default submitToken;
```

Not sure how to solve this problem so that both button onclick event help to update the argument `amountToPut` in `usePrepareContractWrite` before calling `write?.()` ?

---

**Update**
I also tried using `useRef` hooks. It also didn't work.

```js
const amountToPut = useRef<BigNumber>(BigNumber.from("0"));
 const {
    config,
    error: prepareError,
    isError: isPrepareError,
  } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: tokenAddress,
    abi: tokenAbi,
    functionName: "myWritableFun",
    args: [amountToPut.current], // This doesn't update when we change the `partialAmount` in function below
  });
const putPartialToken = () => {
    if (isNaN(Number(debountAmount))) {
      alert("Not a valid amount");
      return;
    }
    // we are checking this in contract too
    if (Number(debountAmount) > totalTokenAmount) {
      alert("Amount overflow!");
      return;
    }
   
    amountToPut.current = utils.parseEther(debouncedStakeAmount); 
    write?.();  
  };

const putAllToken = async () => {      
    amountToPut.current = utils.parseEther(totalTokenAmount.toString()); 
    write?.();
  };
```

Comment: Sanjay, did you figure this out? I'm having a similar issue with a state variable that the UI is updating but isn't making it into the usePrepareContractWrite hook where I need it. 

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I needed to instantiate the state value in the useState().

Comment: No. It didn't worked. Instead I settled with `useContractWrite` and removed `usePrepareContractWrite` completely. If you need to perform input data validation, its really hard.

Answer (score 1):

Use actions instead of hooks:
`import { prepareWriteContract, writeContract } from 'wagmi/actions'`

Answer (score 0):

I found the **refetch** method from **usePrepareContractWrite** and this was enough for me to get the last value in my states.

```
const { config: configRemove, refetch: refetchRemove } =
usePrepareContractWrite({
  address: contractAddress,
  abi: abi.abi,
  functionName: "removeProject",
  from: walletClient?.account?.address,
  args: [removeId.current || 0],
});
```

I used useRef instead of useState.

You can see my production code here: https://github.com/paulobordignon/portfolio/blob/33ff09448b319065e67db4a5dd4bab792bb8b71d/src/components/organisms/Admin/Admin.tsx